# How to use "Chop" kind of operation on whole mathematica file

Tags: complex, error-propagation

In an array of steps including logarithms and integrations, I am finding the problem of small imaginary parts of some o/p's which are complicating/inhibiting the further steps.

I found that "Chop" function can take care of these issues. My problem is that in a complex array with more than hundred equations, it is not possible to find which step is creating the small imaginary part problem, specially when my I/p's are variables.

Is there a way by which we can tell Mathematica that there is no possibility of any complex number o/p on any step and hence do "Chop" kind of operation on the whole file.

thanks in advance

Comment: `Threshold` will probably be more efficient, but in any case `Chop` and `Threshold` are `Listable`, which means they'll automatically apply to every element in a list very efficiently. Just try applying them to all of your data at once.

Comment: Thanks. I never came across the function how can I use say, Threshold for the whole file.

Comment: Literally just apply it to the data you get out of the file all at once. You get an array of data from your `Import` or `ReadList` or whatever. Then use `Threshold` directly on that.

Comment: maybe [$Pre](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/$Pre.html):  i.e., `$Pre = Chop`? as the first line in the notebook and `$Pre =.` as the last line?